# Find sheet name of a worksheet using relative reference

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate 3 lists on one page that shows the A:A range of the previous 3 day's sheets using the INDIRECT formula and concatenation(eg: INDIRECT("'" & B2 & "'!A2") where B2 would equal the name of t, but I need to pull the name of the prior day's sheet (eg: 10-17) into cell B2.

I've got a working function that can find the value of a **cell** in another sheet by relative location, but I can't seem to get the sheet name by relative position.

```
Function NextSheet(rCell As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Integer
    i = rCell.Cells(1).Parent.Index
    NextSheet = Sheets(i + 3).Range(rCell.Address)
End Function
```

and another function that can return the sheet name of the sheet:

```
Function SheetName(rCell As Range, Optional UseAsRef As Boolean) As String
    Application.Volatile
        If UseAsRef = True Then
            SheetName = "'" & rCell.Parent.Name & "'!"
        Else
            SheetName = rCell.Parent.Name
        End If
End Function
```

But I can't seem to use them together (ie: NextSheet(SheetName(A2)), or SheetName(NextSheet(A2)) Is there a similar function I could use to return the sheet name by relative position?

Secondary question: Can I not call a user created function inside of another user created function like that, or are they just not set up correctly to be called inside each other?

Comment: When you use NextSheet what are you expecting as a return?  Currently it will return the ***VALUE*** of a cell on a page 3 from the reference.  And You cannot return the value as range object to Sheetname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1:
You can use the indexing that Excel has for the Sheets objects.

With no error trapping:

```
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Name
'or
Sheets(Sheets("Sheet1").Index + 1).Name
```

You will have to deal with the case of trying this on the last sheet (Error 9: Subscript out of range)

part 2:
Yes, calls can be nested. The return value from one will be passed into the next, so a function like `foo(bar(test(5)))` is valid

Comment: This seems like it would work, but how would I initialize Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Name in VBA?

Comment: the function returns a string. There's no initialization required. You can use another sheet reference in place of `ActiveSheet` if it suits you better